# how to send text to server and get array with volley and json

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I want to send a name to the server and get some images from the server and put image in image slider.

I write this codes

```
private void getrequest(){

    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.43.112/image/items_slider/getdata.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectItemsActivity.this, "boa entrou",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        JSONArray array=new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jo=array.getJSONObject(i);

                            SliderUtils sliderUtils = new SliderUtils();


                            sliderUtils.setSliderImageUrl(jo.getString("game_image"));

                            sliderImg.add(sliderUtils);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(sliderImg, SelectItemsActivity.this);

                    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
                    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
                    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

                    for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++) {

                        dots[i] = new ImageView(SelectItemsActivity.this);
                        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

                        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

                    }

                    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

                    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++) {
                                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));
                            }
                            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectItemsActivity.this, "erro erro",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params=new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("name", name);


            return params;
        }

    };
    rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(SelectItemsActivity.this);
    rq.add(stringRequest);
}
```

dot[] = This is the point at the bottom of the slider to show multiple images

sliderDotspanel = this is a LinearLayout for show dot

sliderImg = this is a list

And writes this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.avm.myapplication, PID: 14867
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
    at com.avm.gamestore.SelectItemsActivity$5.onResponse(SelectItemsActivity.java:386)
    at com.avm.gamestore.SelectItemsActivity$5.onResponse(SelectItemsActivity.java:347)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:78)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

and get error from this

```
dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));
```

please help me this is very important to me

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

As the error is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, it means that your resulting array has zero size. You should check this api on postman or any other platform to confirm that is it really resulting an array.

Comment: Hi tankyou.  im check this in postman and my server code is right in post man

Comment: But im check again tankyou so much